# Commonality in many to many relationship SQL query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

If I have agents that can have many properties, and vice versa, defined in a in a junction table, how would I query the top agents (an agent who has at least two properties in common with two other agents.)

`agent`

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

`properties`

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

`agent_properties`

| agent_id | property_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 6 | 6 |

```
Example:
Agent 1 (propr1, propr2, propr3),
Agent 2 (propr2, propr3),
Agent 3 (propr1, propr3, propr5)
Agent 4 (propr3, propr4, propr6)
Agent 5 (propr1, propr2, propr5)
Agent 6 (propr4, propr6)
```

So the query should return Agent 1, Agent 3, Agent 5

If anyone can show how to do this using Laravel Eloquent that would be great.

Comment: How many properties do you have? It might be a solution if you have less than 32 properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be to work with bits.

*First* you should add a new column in table `properties` and this new column to be named `bin_value`. The values from this column must be unique per property and to be power of 2. In your case would be:

| id | bin_value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 5 | 16 |
| 6 | 32 |

*Second*, add a new column to `agent` table named `properties` and run following update query:

```
UPDATE agent AS a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ap.agent_id, SUM(p.bin_value) AS bin_properties
    FROM agent_properties AS ap
    INNER JOIN properties AS p ON p.id = ap.property_id
    GROUP BY ap.agent_id
) AS b ON a.id = b.agent_id
SET a.properties = b.bin_properties
;
```

*Third*, run the query with bit function which helps you to find agents which have at least 2 shared properties with at least 2 other agents:

```
SELECT a1.agent_id
, a1.name
, COUNT(*) AS total_other_agents
FROM agent AS a1
INNER JOIN agent AS a2 ON a1.id != a2.id 
    AND BIT_COUNT(a1.properties & a2.properties) >= 2 -- at least 2 shared properties
GROUP BY a1.id
HAVING total_other_agents >= 2 -- at least 2 other agents
ORDER BY total_other_agents DESC, a1.name
;
```

If you have a large number of properties try to set values in `bin_value` like this:

```
UPDATE properties
SET bin_value = BINARY(POWER(2, id-1))
;
```